# Pivot Chart not reflecting data correctly

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am a bit new to Pivot charts but I am trying to build a dual axis chart that shows the total purchase order Count and the Average age of purchase orders. I have posted a screen grab of the chart.  The PO count is changing over the dates as I would expect it to but the average age isn't - it is staying flat - even though the data has changed (it is calculated field if that helps (age/total PO).  The odd thing is when I click on the slicer for an employee or manager name, the age does change.  Not sure if I am missing something basic. Thanks[image]

Comment: What data is not reflected correctly? What does the pivot table show? If the results of the calculated field are not what you expect, then the calculated field does not perform correctly. The chart just plots the numbers from the pivot table. Tackle the numbers.

Comment: will try to post some of the actual data

Comment: the issue is that the average age is different on 12/14, 12/20 & 12/27 - it just stays at the number from 12/14 and I can't figure out why when the primary axis is updating from the updates as I would expect

Comment: Is the pivot table showing the correct numbers? If not, don't blame the chart. You need to change the formula for the calculated field. You probably will need power pivot to calculate what you want, or a helper column in your source data.